# In MATLAB if a script only does file i/o and doesn't return anything, how does the function header look like?

Tags: matlab

I always return a dummy variable just for the sake of making it work, but that's not very elegant. Omitting the return value is not possible, i.e.,

```
function = blah()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just

```
function blah()
```

is enough